# Kudu console - revert changes

Tags: azure, web-applications, kudu, azure-app-service-plans

I dragged a whole folder from my computer into the wwwroot in the Kudu console.
Some of the content that I dragged was already existed inside the wwwroot (so it was overwritten) and some not.

Now I don't remember which of the content is new and which not, and I have to delete to **new** content that I added.
Is there any way to go back and revert the changes ?

Comment: All files and folders have date and time tags you can identify and delete as there is no other way for restoring resetting.

Comment: @ZahidFaroq Thank you. As I dragged the whole content together, All files and folders had the same "Modified" field.
Is there another way that you can suggest ?

Comment: There seems no other way as filtering cannot be done

Answer (score 0):

Through my research it seems that **there is no undo\restore option available**.

Yes, it is recommended to use [Backup](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-backup/) feature available for such accidently deletion.

The Backup and Restore feature in Azure App Service lets you easily create app backups manually or automatically. You can restore your app to a previous state, or create a new app based on one of your original app's backups.

You may open a support ticket with our technical team to see the possibility of retrieving the file from the snapshot.